# Django filter that spans relationships but programmatically?

Tags: django, django-models, relation

I understand that to span a relationship in a Django filter you use a double underscore like this:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')
```

However, I have a bunch of dynamic filters that will be determined at runtime.  Can I achieve the same as the above but programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a dictionary and *unpack it into the keyword arguments*:

```
filters = {'entry__headline__contains': 'Lennon'}
Blog.objects.filter(**filters)
```

where `entry__headline__contains` can be dynamically evaluated.